# Removing duplicate strings from python nested list present in any order

Tags: python, list, nested, duplicates, nested-lists

```
[["hello", "bye", "start"], ["bye", "start", "hello"], ["john", "riya", "tom"], ["riya","john", "tom"].....]
```

I have got a list like this. I want to remove duplicate elements from nested list in Python where elements should be in any order.

Output should be:-

```
[["hello", "bye", "start"], ["john", "riya", "tom"]]
```

3 strings should be present only once in any list.
How to achieve this?

Comment: What did you try? Iterate on nested list in a for loop and remove the duplicate elements.

Comment: This isn't entirely clear - given your description, I would have expected two empty lists in your output. So is it that you want to remove entire sub-lists if they are the same as a previous list, disregarding order (in which case a quick and dirty solution might be to use sets), or do you want to remove duplicate strings and also remove any lists that are empty afterwards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `enumerate`:

```
s = [["hello", "bye", "start"], ["bye", "start", "hello"], ["john", "riya", "tom"], ["riya","john", "tom"]]
new_s = [a for i, a in enumerate(s) if not any(all(c in h for c in a) for h in s[:i])]
```

Output:

```
[['hello', 'bye', 'start'], ['john', 'riya', 'tom']]
```

Answer (score 10):

Simply covert in to `set` it removes items automatically.

```
a = [list(i) for i in {frozenset(k) for k in a}]
```

Comment: Excellent answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:-**

```
a = [["hello", "bye", "start"], ["bye", "start", "hello"], ["john", "riya", "tom"], ["riya","john", "tom"]]

ls = []
for i in a:
    i = sorted(i)
    if i not in ls:
        ls.append(i)
print(ls)
```

As u said want to have same output like list then try this tricky method however it won't be pythonic way :-

```
ls = []
ind = []
for i,j in enumerate(a):
    j = sorted(j)
    if j not in ls:
        ind.append(i)
        ls.append(j)
ls1 = [a[x] for x in ind]
print(ls1)
```

**Output:-**

```
[['hello', 'bye', 'start'], ['john', 'riya', 'tom']]
```

Comment: No need of list on list(sorted(i))-> sorted(i).

Comment: Output should be [["hello", "bye", "start"], ["john", "riya", "tom"]] or [["bye", "start", "hello"],["riya","john", "tom"]]. Sorting is not what i wanted. I want to remove duplicate list which contains duplicate strings in whatever order it may be. But output should not change the order, in output it should either be ["hello", "bye", "start"] or ["bye", "start", "hello"]

Answer (score 0):

a simple and naive solution

```
arr = [["hello", "bye", "start"], ["bye", "start", "hello"], ["john", "riya", "tom"], ["riya","john", "tom"]]

seen, tmp, result = list()

for i in arr:
  for j in i:
    if j not in seen:
      seen.append(j)
      tmp.append(j)

      if len(tmp) == 3:
        result.append(tmp)
        tmp = list()

print result
```

keep in mind this will only append list with 3 elements, so some cases may cause absent elements in the output list (as per your example and instructions given)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a pretty simple solution:

```
a = [['hello', 'bye', 'start'], ['bye', 'start', 'hello'], ['john', 'riya', 'tom'], ['riya', 'john', 'tom']]
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i].sort()
for i in a:
    if i not in b:
        b.append(i)
```

it outputs:

```
 [['bye', 'hello', 'start'], ['john', 'riya', 'tom']]
```

Comment: I don't want to sort the list. I want to output the list element in exact same manner, either ['hello', 'bye', 'start'] or ['bye', 'start', 'hello'].